# kendo ui autocomplete, how to bind to load the data?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using the kendo ui autocomplete widget with mvc.

My index.cshtml file is as follows,

```
<div class="filter-value">
    @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("InspectorId")
    .DataTextField("RPersonDetails") 
    )
</div>
```

Rather than put the data source here I want to bind it with javascript.

My javascript code is as follows,

```
wireEvents: function () {

    $("#InspectorId").bind("keyup", function () { AISApp.Page.populateDropDown($(this).val()) });
},


populateDropDown: function (value) {

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: AISApp.Page.getSuburbsURL,
                data: {
                    text: value
                }
            }
        }
    });

  var dd = $('#InspectorId').data("kendoAutoComplete");
dd.setDataSource(dataSource);

},
```

This works, but just wondering is this the correct way to do it or is there a way to do it without using the keyup event, just using the kendo events?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your .cshtml there is a way to use the Kendo helper to bind to a DataSource with your URL. You can then have it automatically re-read the data from the URL when a key is pressed.
Basically it moves your javascript keyup code into the helper's code.

The code would look something like this example:

```
<div class="filter-value">
    @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
          .Name("InspectorId")
          .DataTextField("RPersonDetails")
          .Filter("contains")
          .DataSource(source => {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetProducts", "Home")
                      .Data("onAdditionalData");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })
    )
</div>
<script>
    function onAdditionalData() {
        return {
            text: $("#InspectorId").val() 
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using this.. as it creates global javascript functions.  Is there no other way of binding this later?

Comment: You could just not use the MVC extensions and create the widget in javascript instead. Then you could avoid the global.

Comment: I don't understand how the autocomplete gets the data.  It seems a list needs to be loaded in the controller: